# Error passing New-WebServiceproxy as a function parameter

Tags: powershell, soap, new-webserviceproxy

I'm trying to create a function that uses `New-WebServiceProxy` as a parameter, but I get an error. My function code:

```
function Execute-SOAPRequest () {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        [New-WebServiceproxy]$myService,
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$url
    )

 write-host "Sending SOAP Request To Server: $url" 
 $myService.getUsers()
}
```

The error message:

> ```
> At C:\myService.ps1:6 char:12
> +         [New-WebServiceproxy]$myService,
> +            ~
> Missing ] at end of attribute or type literal.
> At C:\myService.ps1:6 char:13
> +         [New-WebServiceproxy]$myService,
> +             ~
> Parameter declarations are a comma-separated list of variable names with optional initializer expressions.
> At C:\myService.ps1:6 char:13
> +         [New-WebServiceproxy]$myService,
> +             ~
> Missing ')' in function parameter list.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EndSquareBracketExpectedAtEndOfAttribute
> ```

It doesn't like that dash-separated parameter's name [New-WebServiceproxy]. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

`New-WebServiceProxy` is a cmdlet that returns an object of type `WebServiceProxy`. You cannot use a cmdlet to specify the type of your parameter `$myService`, use `WebServiceProxy` instead.